# Dagger do not generates _MembersInjector classes for simple Java project

Tags: java, dagger-2

I'm trying to add Dagger 2 to a simple Java project. It goes like that:

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'java'

dependencies {
    compileOnly "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.12"
    compile "com.google.dagger:dagger:2.12"
}
```

**MainModule**

```
@Module
class MainModule {
    @Provides
    public String providesString () { return "some_string"; }
}
```

**MainComponent**

```
@Singleton
@Component (module = MainModule.class)
interface MainComponent {
    void inject (MainClass main);
}
```

**MainClass**

```
public class MainClass {
    @Inject String sampleDependency;

    public MainClass () {
        DaggerMainComponent
        .builder()
        .build()
        .inject(this);
    }
}
```

On IntelliJ it looks ok, however, when I try to run it I get:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: MainClass_MembersInjector
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Try `annotationProcessor` instead of `compileOnly` for the compiler

Answer (score 0):

Actually the files were being generated but IntelliJ wasn't recognizing them. To solve the problem I went to `Project Structure` (cmd + ; for Mac users) → `Add content root` → Choose the folder that contains dagger2 generated classes.

Comment: Having a similar issue. What was the directory for you?